# Best reference for object size estimation in an image

Tags: image-processing, object-recognition, measurement

I'm working on a project where I need to measure the size of a 2D object on a flat surface from an image. I have total freedom to create a reference with any shape and size.

The camera I am using is the [raspberry pi cam.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/)

My question is simple: what is the best reference to use?

**EDIT:**

Ended up using [this](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) thanks to [Peter K.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/80/peter-k).

Comment: Added some more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to form a calibration plate.  One way to form a calibration plate is to place known-shaped "[fiducials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker)" in a known-sized array on the surface where you want to do the measurement.

Then, knowing the measurements of the calibration plate, you can count pixels and do a map from pixels in each direction (possibly in each area of the image) to real-world measurements.

You also need to know that your camera will always be in a fixed location relative to the measurement surface, and that the lighting is good enough for you to pick up the external shape of the object.

An example of one possible calibration plate is below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I took so long. Thanks for the help! This was definitely the initial push I needed to refine my research. :D